# Grails How to get username in javascript?

Tags: javascript, grails, spring-security

I am working on a Grails application and I want to hide some GUI elements that are dynamically added via Javascript. Therefore I need the username (and userrole) as a variable in my JS code.
I tried to use

```
<g:set var="user" value="${sec.username()}" />
```

But the varibale user is not visible in JS. I know I could use an Ajax request to get the username / role from a controller, but isn't there an easier / faster way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put into current JS context on page load:

```
<g:javascript>
  window.username = '${sec.username}';
</g:javascript>
```

and then use `username` variable in Javascript

Comment: oh yes, if you already `set` user id, then `${user}` will be enough